# Android app (with felix) crashes with LinearAlloc exceeded capacity

Tags: android, osgi, dalvik, apache-felix

I am running apache felix and an osgi app on android (3.2). This works pretty well so far, but I have rather large chunks of data to load into the application (osgi bundles). The problem with that is that when I load the biggest chunk of data I get

> LinearAlloc exceeded capacity

The error seems to come from

LinearAlloc.c

```
\#define DEFAULT_MAX_LENGTH  (4*1024*1024)

 if (nextOffset > pHdr->mapLength) {
    /*
     * We don't have to abort here.  We could fall back on the system
     * malloc(), and have our "free" call figure out what to do.  Only
     * works if the users of these functions actually free everything
     * they allocate.
     */
    LOGE("LinearAlloc exceeded capacity, last=%d\n", (int) size);
    dvmAbort();
}
```

afaik in 3.2/4.x it is even 8*1024*1024, but I still hit that limit. I'm looking to get better insight on what causes this problem and how I might possibly be able to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please report a bug here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry  If you can include a small test case to reproduce, that will make it easier for the Androids to fix your bug.

Answer (score 0):

It's a limitation in Dalvik triggered on unusually complex interface hierarchies.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22586

See the details for ideas on working around. Simple answer might be to try using different libraries that are less complex.

A fix has been merged into Android AOSP. 
https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/30900/